# Click trough scrollviewer in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar, zooming, scrollviewer

Here's the thing, I have a canvas in which I can draw any type of elements but I want to be able to zoom in and out and to use a scroll bar if the canvas gets bigger than the viewport, I though I could use a scrollviewer for it but even when zoom and pan  work just fine I can't access now the canvas that it's contained inside the scrollviewer or its elements.

Comment: Show the XAML of the layout, because it's not clear from your explanation how you achieved this result.
Show the XAML of the layout, because it's not clear from your explanation how you achieved this result.

Comment: Hi,@2al2 . Could you show your code to reproduce the problem? And is it possible to show a screenshot of what is expected and what it actually does?